# react-native-webview disable text selection

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-webview

is there a practical way to disable text selection in react-native webview?
I want to make this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBDoi.png) disabled for the user, which means that the user won't be able to select text of webview presented in app.
I also need to keep links enable to press and navigate from them.

there is no props in react-native-webview that can be used.

there is no access to the server where I get the html I present in the webview.

Answer (score 8):

Use injectedJavascript to disable text selection

```
const INJECTEDJAVASCRIPT = "document.body.style.userSelect = 'none'";
<WebView
  ...
  injectedJavaScript={INJECTEDJAVASCRIPT}
  ...
/>
```

Another way is just wrapping your webview in View Tag

```
<View pointerEvents="none">
  <WebView
    source={{ uri: webviewUrl }}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: but i need to enable links from the webview
the second option disable links

Comment: Try this library https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html#readme It has prop textSelectable